# Overloading operator>> to create array from string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I would like to create an `std::array` from a `std::string`.

For this, I would like to overload the `operator>>`.

I have the following test case:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const std::array<double, 3>& a)
{
    char p1, p2;

    is >> p1;
    // if fail warn the user

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) 
    {
        // something to ignore/ check if numeric
    }

    is >> p2;
    // if fail warn the user
    
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "[1 2 3]";
    std::array<double, 3> arr;
    std::istringstream iss (a);
    iss >> arr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I would like for the operator to check if the characters `[`and `]` are in the correct place and to construct the array with the elements inside.

How can I do checks if the extraction was successfull? How can I check the string between the parenthesis is numeric and if so construct my array from it?

Kind regards

Comment: You'd probably want to set the fail bit of the stream if it's not valid. If you're asking how to check individual characters to see if they're `[` or `]` or similar, then I'd suggest simple if statement. The `istream` already has methods to extra numbers and sets fail bits appropriately.

Comment: Unrelated: How come you can choose between C++11 and C++14 but not C++17 and C++20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a helper class that checks for a certain character in the stream and removes it if it's there. If it's not, sets the failbit.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <istream>

template <char Ch, bool SkipWhitespace = false>
struct eater {
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, eater) {
        if /*constexpr*/ (SkipWhitespace) { // constexpr since C++17
            is >> std::ws;
        }
        if (is.peek() == Ch) // if the expected char is there, remove it
            is.ignore();
        else                 // else set the failbit
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
};
```

And it could then be used like this:

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::array<double, 3>& a) {
    // use the `eater` class template with `[` and `]` as template parameters:
    return is >> eater<'['>{} >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> eater<']'>{};
}

int main() {
    std::string a = "[1 2 3]";
    std::array<double, 3> arr;
    std::istringstream iss (a);
    // iss.exceptions(std::ios::failbit); // if you want exceptions on failure

    if(iss >> arr) {
        std::cout << "success\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "fail\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e56e9z69q) where `,` is used as separator in the input.

Comment: would it be safe to throw an error in the `eater` struct (e.g.,  runTime error for instance)?

Comment: @mysticSnake No need to do that manually - and you shouldn't `throw` unless the user has set the appropriate bit in the stream's exception mask. I added a comment in the code describing how to do that. When that bit is set, `setstate(std::ios::failbit)` will make it throw an exception in `eater` automatically.

Comment: @mysticSnake Did you get it working? Should I add anything more to make the answer acceptable?

Comment: I did. I even made a template for the array for defining the behaviour of an `N` size array. The error I placed after parsing the string. `if (is.fail()) doSomething`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am even trying to see if I can template the  `char` parameter

Comment: @mysticSnake Do you mean something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/erce1jMb7)?